# Initializing a number and a char to a 2D array

Tags: arrays, numbers, 2d, character, initializing

I have to implement a deck of cards with a number and a letter. This is what I have done so far:

```
string deck [6][6] =
{
    {1A, 1B, 1C, 1D},
    {2A, 2B, 2C, 2D},
    {3A, 3B, 3C, 3D},
    {4A, 4B, 4C, 4D},
    {  ,   ,   ,   };

};
int main ()
{
   cout << deck[0][0] << endl;
}
```

I get an error:

> invalid suffix 'A' on integer constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you need to wrap your strings in double quotations.  If you want to use a static initialization/declaration, it should look something like this:

```
std::string deck[4][4] = {
    { "1A", "1B", "1C", "1D"}, 
    { "2A", "2B", "2C", "2D"}, 
    { "3A", "3B", "3C", "3D"}, 
    { "4A", "4B", "4C", "4D"}
};
```

You can display the entire contents of the deck by using two nested `for` loops:

```
for (int r=0; r < 4; ++r) {
    for (int c=0; c < 4; ++c) {
        if (c > 0) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << deck[r][c];
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: ok thank you. To display all the contents in the array, does it have to be a nested loop?

Comment: Yes, or you could just access individual elements as you have done in your OP e.g. `deck[0][0]`.

Comment: i need all the contents to show without writing deck [][] 36 times

Comment: error: too many initializers for 'std::string [6][6] {aka std::basic_string<char> [6][6]}'|

Comment: My answer covers a `4x4` deck, and I will leave it up to you to expand to `6x6` or whatever actual dimension you need.

Comment: it should work if i put it in the main ? or make a separate function or it shouldn't matter

Comment: The loops can be placed inside any function, including `main()`.  The initialization should ideally be placed with the rest of your declarations at the top of your CPP file.

Comment: yes i did that and i still get a "too many initializers" error where my deck array is called

Comment: sorry for the load of questions

Comment: If you copied my code _verbatim_ then there should be no errors.  Please email me your code at TimBeagle@hotmail.com.  No more comments thanks.